# DuckDb - Reading parquet files from S3 - Handling Segmentation Fault Core Dump error

Tags: amazon-s3, segmentation-fault, parquet, duckdb

I receive 1000s of parquet files with same schema every day into a S3 bucket.  I am using duckdb with python3 extension to read all the parquet files to subset data from them.

The following is the snippet of the code I am using :

```
dtt = [array of datetime values]

for dt in dtt:
    print('processing for date :' + str(dt))
    ddt=dt.date()
    dstr=str(dt)
    yr=dstr[0:4]
    mn=dstr[5:7]
    dy=dstr[8:10]

    rurl = "s3://s3bucket/hind/"+str(yr) +'/'+str(mn)+'/'+str(dy)+'/*.parquet'
    nfdf=duckdb.sql("select maid,date,hour,h3id from read_parquet('" + str(rurl) +"') where h3id In " + str(tuple(uhids))).df()
```

The parquet files are of size 25-35 MB each.  The above code works but not always.  I receive `Segmentation Fault Core Dumped` error.  There is no pattern to this error hence I am not able to identify why this fails.

I tried running with various AWS instance types.  The most stable one I find is m6a.4xlarge instance.  However this is very slow.  When I deploy m6a.24xlarge or m6a.48xlarge - it runs faster - but the core dump error also appears very fast.    There is no shortage of RAM or HDD Space.  There are no parallel processing running nor the processor is busy.

I am using the latest version of AWS Cli 2.13.25, Python - 3.8.10, Ubuntu 22.04.  How can I rectify this? I am ready to change the approach if need be.

### Response to Dean's suggestion

I modified the code as follows. Pasting it here, as it may help someone.

I replaced the line `nfdf=duckdb.sql("select....`to the following:

```
tempfil=str('p1_')+str(p)
con=duckdb.connect('file.db')
con.sql('drop table ' + str(tempfil))
con.sql('CREATE TABLE '+str(tempfil)+'(maid text,date date,hour integer,h3id varchar)')
con.sql("insert into " + str(tempfil) + " select maid,date,hour,h3id from read_parquet('" + str(rurl) +"') where h3id In " + str(tuple(uhids)))
ifile="/home/ubuntu/tdata1/p3_"+str(p)+"_"+str(dy)+str(mn)+str(yr)+".parquet"
con.sql("COPY "+ str(tempfil)  +" TO '" + str(ifile)  +"'")
con.table(tempfil).show()
con.sql('drop table ' + str(tempfil))
con.close()
```

@Carlo I use the following code:

```
import duckdb
duckdb.execute("SET home_directory='/home/ubuntu/';")
duckdb.execute("INSTALL httpfs")
duckdb.execute("LOAD httpfs")
duckdb.execute("SET s3_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXX'")
duckdb.execute("SET s3_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXX'")
duckdb.execute("SET s3_region='XXXXXXXX'")

duckdb.sql('PRAGMA platform')
duckdb.sql('PRAGMA version')
duckdb.sql("FROM duckdb_extensions() WHERE extension_name == 'httpfs'")
```

and got the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ddbconfig.py", line 10, in <module>
    duckdb.sql('PRAGMA platform')
duckdb.CatalogException: Catalog Error: Pragma Function with name platform does not exist!
Did you mean "tpch"?
```

Comment: Have you tried not doing a loop and just using wildcards in the `rurl`, for example. `rurl = "s3://s3bucket/hind/*/*/*/*.parquet'`?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thank you for your comment.  Our S3 path has millions of files and for easier retrieval we have set the folder path with year,month and date.  The for loop allows us only to skim through the files in the set path only.

Comment: Even still you should insert the data into a duckdb table instead of materializing then into a bunch of pandas (eww) dataframes

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Ok.  I will try dumping into duckdb table and come back.  Thank you for the suggestion....I was under the impression the duckdb virtual table works only on files stored locally

Comment: @DeacMacGregor I did dump the output into table and read it back to a new parquet file as an output.  Didn;t work.  Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlo from DuckDB Labs here.

This looks similar to something I was independently investigating related to the `httpfs` extension, if this happens to be the same I might be able to help.

---

I believe this should be properly being solved now on either v0.9.1 or any nightly version of DuckDB.

Either
`pip install duckdb==0.9.1` or `pip install duckdb --pre --upgrade`
plus then executing once:

```py
import duckdb
duckdb.execute("FORCE INSTALL httpfs")
```

This will force the newest version of httpfs (this should not be needed if you just installed, but it's required to clear the extensions saved locally).

After this, run your script, and I expect it should work, potentially throwing errors if some of the path are not existing.

Comment: Hi, I have updated by question with the code that I used to run your query and the response I received.

Comment: Can you skip then PRAGMA platform (I think that has been added in 0.9.0, so you likely are version 0.8.x or earlier), and show the other two?
In particular I would be insterested in the install_path it shows for the httpfs extension (that basically encodes the version).

Comment: If the problem happens to the one I have been looking at, there is an HTTPException throw at some point (in the other case due to a non-existing path, but could also be some other problem out of your control) that in a particular situation snow ball into disaster due to an unfortunate series of events. If you can provide the last 2 folders of the `install_path` it would help scope the situation.

Comment: The python code didn;'t print the extension.  However from the duckdb console when I ran `pragma version` - it printed `v0.8.1 ` and for `httpfs extension path and version` it printed `/home/ubuntu.duckdb/extensions/v0.8.1/linux_amd64/httpfs.duckdb_extension`

Comment: This is the issue that looks similar to me: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/9340, but that one I assumed to be Mac-OS related, but I am not sure of that anymore.
Can we move this to a duckdb/duckdb issue (https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/9351), it would be easier for colleagues to join in and follow, I might be able to provide an alternative httpfs extension, mainly to check whether that would solve the problem, and then we can backport the solution in the official extension repo. Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Thank you.  Could you please update here with the repo to download and use when it is ready.  I can check and come back with feedback on this from my end.

Comment: Sure! I will update when I have the artefacts ready on our side.
Do you need to use v0.8.1 or it's possible for you to update to either v0.9.1 (that we plan on back-porting) or nightly (where the artefacts will be ready tomorrow morning)?

Comment: I can update to v0.9.1  and try again.  Please let me know when I can run the updates?

Comment: I updated the answer, I believe that if you can update to v0.9.1 now it should work as expected. Can you potentially check? Thanks

Comment: Thank you.  The new update works flawlessly.  I tried in different aws instance types....they all worked.